# Rocker error of No such file or directory

Tags: docker, rstudio

I am trying to run R-Studio on Docker but when I type the ocmmand to run R-Studio on Docker ($ sudo docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD= --name rstudio rocker/rstudio) I get this error: "password: No such file or directory"

Please let me know how I could fix this and if I need to create a dockerfile for it to run.

I tried to change the ports but that didnt help